# NgbModal: Using a module as an entry component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I have a Feature Module that I would like open with `NgbModal`. However, I am getting this error:

> ERROR Error: No component factory found for CreatePresentationModalModule. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

```
public constructor(private _modalService: NgbModal) { }

public onOpenModal() {
   this._modalService.open(CreatePresentationModalModule);
}
```

```js
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CreatePresentationModalComponent,
        CreatePresentationStep1,
        CreatePresentationStep2
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        CreatePresentationModalComponent
    ]
})
export class CreatePresentationModalModule { }
```

Based on what the error says I add the module to the entry components of the root module, but then I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: CreatePresentationModalModule cannot be used as an entry component.

How can I open my module with `NgbModule`?

Comment: what do you mean by rendering a Module? render component instead

Comment: I don't know what you mean by **rendering**? I never used that term in the question.

Comment: @Andrei I am using `NgbModal` to open a modal. `NgbModal.open()` takes a component as a parameter, but the modal I want to open is a `Module`, how can I pass it a module instead of a component?

Comment: It seems as if all I need to do is add `CreatePresentationModalComponent` to the `exports` of my module, then use it in `NgbModal.open(CreatePresentationModalComponent) `